# Combining Turtle and Tkinter Module into One Big Class

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I created two different windows for a project. The first window is `Demo1` using the turtle module for Python and the second window is `Demo2` using the Tkinter for Python.I created two different programs for each window and wanted to combine both windows into one large project full of windows for final project in a class. The only problem is Window 2 doesn't work once I created a class for coding of the window and this class is inside a larger class with all the coding of the windows combined. Is there a better way for this code to be written or could someone fix it to run appropriately.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import random
from graphics import *
import turtle

from time import sleep

class Intro():

    def __init__(self,master):

        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("800x300")
        self.master.title("Welcome")
        self.master.configure(background = 'blue')
        self.label1 = Label(self.master,text ="Event Driven Programming Demonstration", fg = "white", bg = "blue",font = ("Purisa",18)).grid(row =1,column = 2)
        self.label2 = Label(self.master,text ="Program created by Ariel Lyons & Aaron Brown for CSC322 FSU 2014",font = ("Purisa",18), fg = "white",bg = "blue").grid(row = 2, column = 2)
        self.quitButton = Button(self.master,text ="Quit", fg="Black",bg = "red",command=self.finish).grid(row =18,column =2)
        self.nextButton = Button(self.master,text = "Demo 1", fg ="Black",bg = "yellow",command =self.goToDemo1).grid(row = 14, column =2)
        self.Demo2Button = Button(self.master,text = "Demo 2", fg = "Black", bg = "yellow",command = self.goToDemo2).grid(row = 16, column = 2)
        self.master.bind("<Return>", self.goToDemo1)

    def goToDemo1(self):
        threading.Timer(5.0, goToDemo1).start()
        root2 = Toplevel(self.master)
        myGUI = Demo1(root2)

    def goToDemo2(self):
        try: 
           app = Demo2() 
           app.th.start() 
           app.win.mainloop() 
           app.th.join() 
        finally: 
           app.th.close() 
           app.close() 


    def goToDemo1(self):
        root2 = Toplevel(self.master)
        myGUI = Demo1(root2)

    def finish(self):
        self.master.destroy()


class Demo1():

    def __init__(self,t):
        self.t = turtle.Turtle() 
        ts = self.t.getscreen() 
        ts.register_shape("plane.gif") 
        self.t.shape("plane.gif") 
        self.t.pencolor("white") 
        ts.onscreenclick(self.t.goto) 
        ts.bgpic('sky.gif') 
        self.t.circle(50,400)
        self.t.circle(100,500)

    def goToDemo2(self):

       root3=Toplevel(self.t)
       myGUI = Demo2(root3)

    def finish(self):
        self.t.destroy()


class Demo2():

    def __init__(self): 
        self.win = GraphWin('Demo2', 800, 600)
        self.win.setBackground("light green")
        self.th = threading.Thread(target=self.FlashThread, daemon=False) 
    def FlashThread(self): 
        while not self.win.isClosed(): 
            count = random.randint(0, 8) 
            t = threading.Timer(1.0, self.flash, [count]) 
            t.start() 
            t.join() 
    def flash(self, count): 
        try: 
            diameter = 50
            centers = ((55,55),  (170,55), (285,55),  (55,170), (170,170),  
                       (285,170), (55,285), (170,285), (285,285)) 
            circles = list() 
            for point in centers: 
                c = Circle(Point(point[0], point[1]), diameter) 
                circles.append(c) 
                c.setFill("blue") 
                c.draw(self.win) 
            circles[count].setFill("yellow") 
            mouseClick = self.win.getMouse() 
            correctMessage = Text(Point(self.win.getWidth()/2, 20), 'Correct!') 
            incorrectMessage = Text(Point(self.win.getWidth()/2, 20), 'Incorrect,Try Again') 
            leftX  = centers[count][0] - diameter 
            rightX = centers[count][0] + diameter 
            upperY = centers[count][1] - diameter 
            lowerY = centers[count][1] + diameter 
            if (upperY < mouseClick.y < lowerY) and (leftX < mouseClick.x < rightX):
                correctMessage.draw(self.win)
                print("Correct!")
            else:                
                incorrectMessage.draw(self.win)
                print("Incorrect, Try Again")
        except: 
            self.win.close() 

def main():

    root = Tk()
    myGUIIntro = Intro(root)
    root.mainloop()



if __name__ =="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess I'm not understanding your question. Are you trying to have two windows created but have only one class? And what do you mean that window 2 doesn't work?